# Got the error Failed to execute goal org.teavm:teavm-maven-plugin:0.5.1, error occured: Cannot invoke "org.teavm.model.MethodReader.getAnnotations()

Tags: javascript, java

I tried to include a Java library `org.worldcubeassociation.tnoodle.scrambles.Puzzle` and I tried to invoke a method of the abstract class Puzzle. I got an error while building the wasm. The error I am getting is:

```
Failed to execute goal org.teavm:teavm-maven-plugin:0.5.1:compile (hello) on project UpcubeScrambler: Unexpected error occured: Cannot invoke "org.teavm.model.MethodReader.getAnnotations()" because "method" is null -> [Help 1]
```

I tried to search for a solution but couldn't get any.

I don't work with Java much. I need to implement this functionality in the front end itself, but the Tnoodle(library) is only available in java.
Please help me here.

This is the Java code:

```java
package com.cubelelo;

import org.teavm.interop.Export;
import org.teavm.interop.Import;
import org.worldcubeassociation.tnoodle.puzzle.*;
import org.worldcubeassociation.tnoodle.scrambles.Puzzle;

public class ScrambleLogic {
    @Export(name = "getScramble")
    public static void getScramble(String puzzleType) {
        Puzzle puzzle = new ThreeByThreeCubePuzzle();
        String scramble = puzzle.generateScramble();
        setScramble(scramble);
    }

    @Import(module = "env", name = "setScramble")
    private static native void setScramble(String scramble);
}
```

This is the example code for the browser:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Scrambler</title>
    <style>
      section.container {
        margin: 3em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function setScramble(scramble) {
        console.log("WASM code has called the setScramble method.");
        console.log("WASM set the scramble " + scramble);
      }
      WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("./scramblelogic.wasm"), {
        env: { setScramble },
      }).then((module) => {
        console.log("Calling the wasm module from JavaScript.");
        module.instance.exports.getScramble("333");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the log:

```
PS C:\Users\njp28\Workspace\Projects\UpcubeScrambler> mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building UpcubeScrambler 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ UpcubeScrambler ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ UpcubeScrambler ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\njp28\Workspace\Projects\UpcubeScrambler\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- teavm-maven-plugin:0.5.1:compile (hello) @ UpcubeScrambler ---
[INFO] Preparing classpath for JavaScript generation
[INFO] Using the following classpath for JavaScript generation: C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\org\worldcubeassociation\tnoodle\lib-scrambles\0.18.
0\lib-scrambles-0.18.0.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\org\worldcubeassociation\tnoodle\lib-svglite\0.18.0\lib-svglite-0.18.0.jar:C:\Users\njp28
\.m2\repository\org\timepedia\exporter\gwtexporter\2.5.1\gwtexporter-2.5.1.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\org\teavm\teavm-classlib\0.5.1\teavm-
classlib-0.5.1.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\org\teavm\teavm-platform\0.5.1\teavm-platform-0.5.1.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\org\teavm\t
eavm-core\0.5.1\teavm-core-0.5.1.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\org\teavm\teavm-interop\0.5.1\teavm-interop-0.5.1.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\reposi
tory\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\com\carrotsearch\hppc\0.6.1\hppc-0.6.1.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repo
PS C:\Users\njp28\Workspace\Projects\UpcubeScrambler> mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building UpcubeScrambler 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ UpcubeScrambler ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ UpcubeScrambler ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- teavm-maven-plugin:0.5.1:compile (hello) @ UpcubeScrambler ---
[INFO] Preparing classpath for JavaScript generation
[INFO] Using the following classpath for JavaScript generation: C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\org\worldcubeassociation\tnoodle\lib-scrambles\0.18.0\lib-scrambles-0.18.0.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\org\worldcubeassociation\tnoodle\lib-svglite\0.18.0\lib-svglite-0.18.0.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\org\timepedia\exporter\gwtexporter\2.5.1\gwtexporter-2.5.1.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\org\teavm\teavm-classlib\0.5.1\teavm-classlib-0.5.1.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\org\teavm\teavm-platform\0.5.1\teavm-platform-0.5.1.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\org\teavm\teavm-core\0.5.1\teavm-core-0.5.1.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\org\teavm\teavm-interop\0.5.1\teavm-interop-0.5.1.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\reposi
tory\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\com\carrotsearch\hppc\0.6.1\hppc-0.6.1.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repo
sitory\org\teavm\teavm-jso\0.5.1\teavm-jso-0.5.1.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\org\teavm\teavm-jso-apis\0.5.1\teavm-jso-apis-0.5.1.jar:C:\User
s\njp28\.m2\repository\org\teavm\teavm-jso-impl\0.5.1\teavm-jso-impl-0.5.1.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\org\mozilla\rhino\1.7.7\rhino-1.7.7.j
ar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm-debug-all\5.2\asm-debug-all-5.2.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4
\gson-2.2.4.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\com\jcraft\jzlib\1.1.3\jzlib-1.1.3.jar:C:\Users\njp28\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.7\joda-time-2.7.jar:C:\Users\njp28\Workspace\Projects\UpcubeScrambler\target\classes
[INFO] Building JavaScript file
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.620s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu May 25 12:43:29 IST 2023
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/54M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.teavm:teavm-maven-plugin:0.5.1:compile (hello) on project UpcubeScrambler: Unexpected error occured: Cannot invoke "org.teavm.model.MethodReader.getAnnotations()" because "method" is null -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This is the pop.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.cubelelo</groupId>
    <artifactId>UpcubeScrambler</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.worldcubeassociation.tnoodle</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-scrambles</artifactId>
            <version>0.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.teavm</groupId>
            <artifactId>teavm-classlib</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/webapp</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                        <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                    <mainClass>fi.iki.elonen.SimpleWebServer</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-d</argument>
                        <argument>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.nanohttpd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>nanohttpd-webserver</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.teavm</groupId>
            <artifactId>teavm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>hello</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.cubelelo.ScrambleLogic</mainClass>
                        <targetDirectory>${project.build.directory}/webapp/wasm</targetDirectory>
                        <targetFileName>scramblelogic.wasm</targetFileName>
                        <targetType>WEBASSEMBLY</targetType>
                        <optimizationLevel>FULL</optimizationLevel>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have used the above code to run the Java code in the JavaScript.

I got the error while running the code.
Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are using quite old version of TeaVM, please use most recent version (if possible, use [preview build](https://teavm.org/docs/intro/preview-builds.html)).
2. I consider starting from JavaScript target instead of WebAssembly. WebAssembly support is experimental in TeaVM and has some difficulties to deal with. I would recommend to compile to JavaScript and if everything goes fine, try to "upgrade" to WebAssembly.
3. TeaVM was never designed to port libraries, so you should always have "main" method, and in case of WebAssembly you should always call "main" first, to give TeaVM a chance to properly initialize VM. If you get success with compiling default entry point, please, contact me so that I helped you to create alternative entry points.
4. It would be great if you could share full configuration, including source code and simple reproducible list of steps that help to reproduce the issue.

I consider using [issue tracker](https://github.com/konsoletyper/teavm/issues) for further communication.

UPDATE: added my own example. The only issue was absence of SecureRandom class, for which I created a simple replacement. See https://github.com/konsoletyper/tnoodle-example